# find likewise data from two tables in mysql

Tags: php, sql, select, mysql

i have two tables in my database one is A other one is B
A is having few fields in which three are id,name,group
B is having feilds like id,title,description, etc.

i have to search the id's of title and description that are having data similar to table A's name or group and then have to insert the id's in a field of table A.

For example,
if A is having 'Anna' in its name and 'girl' in its group then i have to search the title's and descriptions in table B that are containing this word 'Anna' or 'girl'.

I want to do this in one single query.

How can i do so?

Edit:
Iam explainng my tables here for a better understanding

```
 table A

id     name     group     matched_id
1       anna     girl
2       sydney   girl
3        max      boy                             etc.

Table B

id      title                                      description
1       A good girl                             Anna is a very good girl
2      Max doesnt work hard                    Boys are always like that only
```

etc...

see i will first search for a match for 'anna' in the table B's title and description and if a match is found in either of them then i'll store that id in table A only in the field 'matched id'
I'll do the same procedure for 'girl' and then for 'sydney' and so on

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to insert B.id into a new/not listed field from table A?

Comment: The problem still remains, where do you want to put the IDs if you found a match? and what happens if you find more than one matching ID? (will happen easily for the groups).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query should do the trick:

```
UPDATE a SET matched_id =
 (SELECT b.id FROM b
  WHERE b.title LIKE CONCAT(' % ',a.name,' % ')
  OR b.description LIKE CONCAT('% ',a.name,' %')
  OR b.title LIKE CONCAT('%',a.group,'%')
  OR b.description LIKE CONCAT('%',a.group,'%')
  LIMIT 1)
WHERE EXISTS
 (SELECT a.id FROM b
  WHERE b.title LIKE CONCAT('% ',a.name,' %')
  OR b.description LIKE CONCAT('% ',a.name,' %')
  OR b.title LIKE CONCAT('%',a.group,'%')
  OR b.description LIKE CONCAT('%',a.group,'%')
  LIMIT 1)
```

Some remarks to this:

- LIMIT 1 was necessary, as each subquery can and will return more than 1 row
- Not 100% sure if the order you want/need is used, you may need some further testing for that and use order by if needed
- it may also be better to use an extra table for the groups (to reduce duplicate entries) and maybe one extra mapping table, so that you can map all results from B to A

**EDIT:**
if names need to match perfectly (unlike girl/girls), you can just add a space in front of the name: '% ',a.name,' %'. If it gets more complicated I would suggest using regular expressions (REGEX). I modified the query with the spaces (for names only), so feel free to try it again.

Comment: your query has done it almost but now the problem is that if there's a name like 'LT' then it is giving matches in even those title/desc where exact 'LT' is not written.For eg. I am consulting.
In this this query is giving match for LT as we have it in consulting.
I want to match the word exactly.It should only match the sentence like "i and LT went together'

Comment: adding another OR should not be a problem, accepting and taking away the accept just because you can't add a simple modification on your own is a bit sad. This query should fit your needs you specified in the question and it is very easy to adopt to your new needs. As I also stated in the answer, if it gets too complicated, check REGEX.

Comment: i know fank that i can add up another OR in this query and its not a problem at all...the thing is i dont want to write again and again in my query and dont want to make it complicated. Iam checking regex only but thought if anyone can help me with regex as i need to finish this work quickly.Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    A
JOIN    B
ON      b.title IN (a.name, a.group)
        OR b.description IN (a.name, a.group)
WHERE   a.name = 'Anna'
        AND a.group = 'girl'
```

Since `INDEX_UNION`'s are not very efficient in `MySQL`, it may be better to split the queries (especially if your tables are `InnoDB`):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  b.id
        FROM    A
        JOIN    B
        ON      b.title IN (a.name, a.group)
        WHERE   a.name = 'Anna'
                AND a.group = 'girl'
        UNION
        SELECT  b.id
        FROM    A
        JOIN    B
        ON      b.description IN (a.name, a.group)
        WHERE   a.name = 'Anna'
                AND a.group = 'girl'
        ) bo
JOIN    B
ON      b.id = bo.id
```